# Pygame - Import Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pygame, importerror

I have downloaded pygame for 64 bit and when I try to import pygame , I keep on getting the following error.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Python\test 2\test_2.py", line 4, in <module>
> import pygame
> ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
> ```

Comment: Seems like it can't find it, how exactly did you install pygame?

Comment: Also outside of this case, where the library is likely uninstalled, it is nearly impossible to debug on an error message alone... You should post relevant portions (with necessary context) of your code (`test_2.py`).

Comment: None of that is working for me it keeps failing to import

Comment: I found out what it was i installed it in the wrong folder sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note

> According to http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
> NOTE: if you
> had pygame 1.7.1 installed already, please uninstall it first.  Either
> using the uninstall feature - or remove the files:
> c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pygame

## Direct download link for python

Downoad link for python 2.7.11 ===> [Here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.msi)

## Direct download link for pygame

Download link for pygame ===> [Here](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi)

**Make sure you install the correct python version and pygame version.Dont mix up the two.**
The links I have provided are **ONLY** for windows and not any other operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to make sure you are downloading the correct version of pygame with python. Try redownloading pygame, and when your downloading it should say if it finds the proper python in the directory, if it doesn't theres a problem with the version you/your downloaded/downloading.